# How to explain these statistical results in layman terms?

Tags: r, statistical-significance

Overall, the evidence that subjects rate qualifications differently according to handicap status is moderately
strong and is statistically significant at the α = 0.05 level (F = 2.862, p = 0.03). The data also provide
sufficient evidence to suggest that there is a systematic difference between the average qualification scores
given to the crutches candidate and to the hearing-impaired candidate. The difference is estimated to be 1.87
points higher for the crutches handicap, with a 95% confidence interval from 0.14 to 3.60 points based on the
Tukey’s HSD. In addition, we find evidence of a significant difference between the average scores given to
the wheelchair and crutches handicaps compared to the average scores given to the amputee and hearing
handicaps (t = 3.19, p = 0.002, for a linear contrast). Notably, none of the average qualification scores from the
four physical handicap groups differ significantly from the no-handicap control.

Comment: For what it's worth, the same terminology shows up on Chegg [here](https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/required-packages-sleuth3-mosaic-agricolae-gmodels-overview-us-vocational-rehabilitation-a-q69243142) and [here](https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/us-vocational-rehabilitation-act-1973-prohibited-discrimination-people-physical-disabiliti-q20383197). Homework questions are allowed on CV, but you need to show us what you've tried so far and say exactly where you get stuck: you won't have much luck if you just ask people to give you the answer

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us what you understand thus far, what 
you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to 
help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you 
is grounds for closing.